# 2 parent selectors at different levels of SASS nesting output to the same level in CSS?

Tags: sass

How can I have 2 different parent selectors in my SASS that are at different levels of nesting, but which are outputted to the same level?

So I need an output like this:

```
.body-1.body-a .element {
    color: red;
}

.body-1.body-b .element {
    color: blue;
}
```

This is my attempt so far:

```
.element {
    .body-1 & {
        &.body-a & {
            color: red;
        }

        &.body-b & {
            color: blue;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the same as this question but for SASS not LESS: [Have 2 classes as parent selectors at different levels in Less?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727945/have-2-classes-as-parent-selectors-at-different-levels-in-less)

Comment: Alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764498/is-it-possible-to-reference-a-further-parent-than-just-the-one-above

Comment: @cimmanon I dont see this as a duplicate of that question.